# Why do URL parameters use %-encoding instead of a simple escape character

Tags: http, url, encoding

For example, in Unix, a backslash (\) is a common escape character. So to escape a full stop (.) in a regular expression, one does this:

```
\.
```

But with % encoding URL parameters, we have an escape character, %, *and* a control code, so an ampersand (&) doesn't become:

```
%&
```

Instead, it becomes:

```
%26
```

Any reason why? Seems to just make things more complicated, on the face of it, when we could just have one escape character and a mechanism to escape itself where necessary:

```
%%
```

Then it'd be:

1. simpler to remember; we just need to know which characters to escape, not which to escape and what to escape them *to*
2. encoding-agnostic, as we wouldn't be sending an ASCII or Unicode representation explicitly, we'd just be sending them in the encoding the rest of the URL is going in
3. easy to write an encoder: `` s/[!\*'();:@&=+$,/?#\[\] "%-\.<>\\^_`{|}~]/%&/g `` (untested!)
4. better because we could switch to using `\` as an escape character, and life would be simpler and it'd be summer all year long

I might be getting carried away now. Someone shoot me down? :)

*EDIT*: replaced two uses of "delimiter" with "escape character".

Answer (score 1):

Percent encoding happens not only to escape delimiters, but also so that you can transport bytes that are not allowed inside URIs (such as control characters or non-ASCII characters).

Comment: I'm going to edit the question. When I said delimiter I meant escape character. My examples were meant to make it clear, but perhaps not!

Answer (score -2):

I guess it's because the URL Specification and specifically the HTTP part of it, only allow certain characters so to escape those one must replace them with characters that are allowed.

Also some allowed characters have special meanings like & and ? etc
so replacing them with a control code seems the only way to solve it

If you find it hard to recognize them, bookmark this page
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: Er yeah, I think that's covered in the question :)

Comment: well i think it answers the question perfectly, the fact that you don't  like it doesn't change that :)

Comment: I admire your self confidence, but it's not that you're right and I just don't like it, it's that the question acknowledges what you're saying and asks why it's like that. Please re-read it before commenting hastily.